# How to view dynamo DB logs | Dynamo Mapper Issue

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function which tries to save an item to dynamo DB. Following is the code snippet which does that:

```
AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDBClient = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).build();
logger.log("dynamoDBClient instantiated"+dynamoDBClient);
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);
logger.log("Invoking save"+mapper);
mapper.save(user);
```

i have populated user object with the values that i want to set into the table. When i execute my lambda function the logs displayed in cloudwatch is

dynamoDBClient instantiatedcom.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient@6221a451

I do not see the logs "Invoking save". This means that something when wrong when DynamoMapper was instantiated. However i dont see any logs in cloudwatch.

What am i doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That code looks fine.

What is your lambda timeout set to, and how long does the process execute for before it stops? I'm wondering if your process is timing out?

Im also wondering if you are packaging the DynamoDB SDK Library with your code correctly? Maybe you could share your build file?